# How to update an object in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

i have build a simple BlockChain in nodejs. in the wallet class, i can subtract the balance, but it cant be added. Here is the Wallet class:

```
class Wallet {
    constructor(){
        const keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa',{
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: {type: 'spki', format: 'pem'},
            privateKeyEncoding: {type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem'}
        });
        this.privateKey = keyPair.privateKey;
        this.publicKey = {key: keyPair.publicKey, balance: 0}
    }
    sendMoney(amount,receiverPublicKey,senderPrivateKey){
        const transaction = new Transaction(this.publicKey.key,receiverPublicKey,amount);

        const sign = crypto.createSign("SHA256");
        sign.update(transaction.toString()).end();

        const signature = sign.sign(this.privateKey);
        Bitcoin.addBlock(transaction,this.publicKey.key,signature);
       if(senderPrivateKey === this.privateKey && receiverPublicKey !== this.publicKey.key){
           this.publicKey.balance -= amount;
       }else if(receiverPublicKey === this.publicKey.key && senderPrivateKey !== this.privateKey){
           this.publicKey.balance += amount;
       }
    }
}
```

and here is how i initiate a transaction :

```
const satoshi = new Wallet();
const bob = new Wallet();

satoshi.publicKey.balance = 500;

satoshi.sendMoney(400,bob.publicKey.key,satoshi.privateKey);
```

How can i make the amount be added to the balance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `satoshi.sendMoney()`, then "`this`" will refer to satoshi's wallet.
This means, by doing `this.publicKey.balance += amount;`, you are trying to update satoshi's balance, not bob's. You could use `receiverPublicKey` instead, to increase the receiver's balance.

The example below updates both wallets. It could still be wrong because I removed some checks, but I hope it helps.

```js
sendMoney(amount, receiverPublicKey, senderPrivateKey) {
    const transaction = new Transaction(this.publicKey.key,receiverPublicKey.key,amount);
    const sign = crypto.createSign("SHA256");
    sign.update(transaction.toString()).end();
    const signature = sign.sign(this.privateKey);
    Bitcoin.addBlock(transaction,this.publicKey.key,signature);

    if (senderPrivateKey === this.privateKey && receiverPublicKey.key !== this.publicKey.key) {
        this.publicKey.balance -= amount;
        receiverPublicKey.balance += amount;
    }
}
```

```js
console.log(satoshi.publicKey.balance) // 500
console.log(bob.publicKey.balance)     // 0

satoshi.sendMoney(400, bob.publicKey/*.key*/, satoshi.privateKey);

console.log(satoshi.publicKey.balance) // 100
console.log(bob.publicKey.balance)     // 400
```